# How to acess parent object properties from child object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

How can I access parent object properties from the child object in JavaScript.

```
function testingSetValuetoInheritedProperty() {
    
   let m = {x:1,y:2};
    
   let n = Object.create(m);
    
   **console.log(n.prototype.x);**
    
   return n
    
}
```

I am getting  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to access property of an object.

```js
function testingSetValuetoInheritedProperty() {

   let m = {x:1,y:2};
   let n = Object.create(m); // m becomes a prototype of object n

   //first - dot property accessor
   console.log(n.x);
   //second - square brackets property accessor
   console.log(n['x']);
   //third - object destructuring
   const { x } = n;
   console.log(x)
   
   
   console.log('-------Prototype------')

   //working with prototype of n

   //first
   console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(n).x)
   //second
   console.log(n.__proto__.x) // <--- no longer recommended

}

testingSetValuetoInheritedProperty()
```

**For your reference**: [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in more detail.

**Prototypes:** [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and [Object.prototype.**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

---

Please note that if you do:

```
   let m = {x:1,y:2};

   let n = Object.create(m);
```

Then both `n` and `m` are objects. It means that you can use the above examples to access their properties.

Comment: But, my question is how to access parent props from child

Comment: Sorry, I slightly misunderstood the question. I edited the answer to account for working with the prototypes but it seems that you have figured it out already. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

To access the properties of prototype object use: `Object.getPrototypeOf()`

```js
function testingSetValuetoInheritedProperty() {
     
   let m = {x:1,y:2};
   let n = Object.create(m);
     
   console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(n).x)
}
testingSetValuetoInheritedProperty()
```